# How to SELECT with the given tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_permissions` (
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permission_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `user_id_fk` (`user_id`),
  KEY `permission_id_fk` (`permission_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `permission_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `permissions` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
```

Given the above tables, how can I perform a SELECT that will return `<users.name> | <true / false>` if a specific user.id has permissions.id 1, 2, 3 and 4 based on the `user_permissions` n:m table?

Something like:

```
SELECT users.name, (..something..) as valid FROM user_permissions WHERE users.id 1 has 1,2,3 and 4 permissions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join of `users` to `user_permissions`, group by user and conditional aggregation:

```
select
  u.id, u.name,
  case count(up.permission_id) 
    when 4 then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end result
from users u left join user_permissions up
on up.user_id = u.id and up.permission_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by u.id, u.name
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I'm doing some testing and it seems that group by isn't needed at all, what am I missing?

Comment: Without group by u.id, u.name how can you aggregate on each user? You need to count for each user if they have all 4 permissions.

Comment: Oh.. I see the issue here. That's because I added a `where u.id=<some user id>`, thats why group by wasn't needed on my testing I assume.